# Multiple Activities adMob

Tags: android-studio, admob

I have 9 Activities in my project
I want to display admob selected activities
but, if I implements in each activities, 
it shows difference one and little slow.

Also, how to make InterstitialAd?

can anybody give me some example code
and perfect explanation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 9 Activities you are almost certainly going to be better off having a single Activity and 9 Fragments that you switch between. NB this is just a general Android statement.

But having done that then you can have a single AdView outside your Fragments that will then show for all of them.

As for Interstitials, I suggest you look at the Admob examples. They are extremely clear and easy to follow.